# Python. Сравнение переменной с числом из списка

Tags: python, list, while

Имеется список фиксированных чисел **y=[1,45,66,22,1988]**, а также имеется переменная **x=random.randrange(1,1999)**

Я пытаюсь прогнать переменную **x** в цикле **While** до тех пор, пока **x** не станет равна одному из чисел списка **y**

```
y = [1,45,66,22,1988]
x = 0

while ( x not in y ):
   print("X = ",x)
   x = random.randrange(0,1999)
```

Проблема в том, что цикл может остановиться, если даже **x** не будет равен одному из чисел списка **y**. Последним результатом было число **305**.

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Теоретически, возможна ситуация, когда у вас цикл никогда не остановится, т.к. никогда не выпадет число из списка. Событие маловероятное, даже очень-и-очень маловероятное, но зачем рисковать? Гораздо проще же число брать не из ранга по значению, а из ранга по количеству: `x = random.randrange(0, len(y))`, тогда полученный `x` - это ключ требуемого элемента (`y[x]`). И элемент из списка всегда будет найден за одну итерацию, а не за какой-то случайный промежуток времени.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы не печатаете последнее значение `X`, которое попадает в список `y`:

```
y = [1,45,66,22,1988]
x = 0

while ( x not in y ):
    print("X = ",x)
    x = random.randrange(0,1999)

print("X in y, X=", x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Я рискую ответить немного не по теме, но возможно будет полезно. Что вы хотите своим кодом добиться? Выбрать произвольное из списка `y`? Тогда лучше сделать это так:

```
from random import choice

y = [1,45,66,22,1988]
x = choice(y)
```